# How to build a Spring form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp

I have a `.jsp` view page which constructs a table dynamically at load time. A snippet of the table is shown below:

[image]

Depending on a parameter `personFilename` being non-empty, each row either has or doesn't have a `Download` button at the end. Clicking this button sends the values in the row to the Java Spring controller method which downloads a file corresponding to that person in the browser.

There are also two input text fields for `start` and `end` ages and a `Filter` button on the same view page. Clicking this button must delete the entire table and dynamically built another one where we only include the rows having the `Age` in the desired range.

What I am struggling with is the creation of this new table in JavaScript. I do not know how to put the spring's `<form:form...>...</form:form>` as the `innerHTML` of the row's cell. This is essential since I want the mapping from button-click to controller to work as it does in the original form built on the initial load of the `.jsp` view page.

I know that spring forms cannot be built in JavaScript, so is there an alternative which can help me create the table with buttons that map to the Java controller method?

Here is the relevant `.js` code followed by the relevant portion from `.jsp` file.

```js
function deleteWholeTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var rows = table.rows;
    var i = rows.length;
    while (--i) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
    }
}

function appendRowToTable(name, age, personFilename) {
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    // get the current length of the table
    var rowsOfTable = table.rows.length; 
    // insert a new row at the end
    var row = table.insertRow(rowsOfTable);
    // put name and age in cells 1 and 2
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); cell1.innerHTML = name;
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); cell2.innerHTML = age;
    if (personFilename){
        var cell8 = row.insertCell(7); cell8.innerHTML =
        // WHAT TO WRITE HERE?  CAN'T MAKE A SPRING FORM AS DONE IN JSP FILE
        // NEED TO INSERT A FORM WITH BUTTON THAT SENDS DATA TO /downloadPersonFile WHEN IT IS CLICKED (just like in jsp file)
    }
    else{
        var cell8 = row.insertCell(7); cell8.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<%--other irrelevant stuff here--%>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <input type="text" id="ageStart" placeholder="Start Age..">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <input type="text" id="ageEnd" placeholder="End Age..">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" id="filterData">Filter</button>
</div>


<%--this is the outer form--%>
 <form:form  id = "outerForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="detailList" >
    <div id="tableDiv" >
        <table id = "dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " >
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Download File</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${detailList.personDetailList}" var="personDetail" varStatus="tagStatus">
                <tr>
                    <td>${personDetail.name}</td>
                    <td>${personDetail.age}</td>
                    <td>
                    <%--this is the spring form that I care about and want to recreate in JS--%>
                        <form:form method = "POST" action = "/downloadPersonFile">
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${empty (personDetail.personFilename)}">
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                <%--when the personFilename is non-empty, add a download button--%>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="personDetail" value="${personDetail.name},${personDetail.age},${personDetail.personFilename}">Download</button>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        </form:form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</form:form>
              
              
<script>
$('#filterData').on('click', function (e) {
    // first we delete the table built above and then rebuilt it only using the rows where age is in desired range
   deleteWholeTable();
   var startAge = $('#ageStart').val();
   var endAge = $('#ageEnd').val();
   <c:forEach items="${detailList.personDetailList}" var="personDetail" varStatus="tagStatus">
       var personAge = "${personDetail.age}";
       // convert personAge, startAge, endAge to integer
       if (personAge >= startAge && personAge <= endAge ){
            appendRowToTable("${personDetail.name}", "${personDetail.age}","${personDetail.personFilename}");
       }
   </c:forEach>
});

</script>
```

Here is the Java controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPersonFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, params={"personDetail"})
public ModelAndView  getAndDownloadPersonFile(@RequestParam("personDetail") String personDetail, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        String personAttr[] = personDetail.split(",");
        // the following function fetches the file from database and downloads it in browser 
        fetchAndDownload(personAttr[0], personAttr[1], personAttr[2], response);
        return null;
}
```

I am new to JavaScript and Spring MVC framework in general. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use AJAX for this. The idea is to request a url like `personTable.jsp?minage=30&maxage=40` (using fetch()) and insert the result into your document. The relevant controller in turn only sends back the HTML code for the table, not a full document. In other words: you cannot use Spring tags on the client side.

Comment: @ChrisG I am not much experienced with AJAX and I am not sure if I understood you correctly. Let me clarify. So, the thing is once this jsp page loads with the initial table, the user sees the table built within the jsp page as shown in code above. Now it is filtered based on ages and this is not a call to any controller, but simply a call to a JS method which builds a new table. What I want to know is how to build this table in JS while retaining the mapping of the download buttons to controller. So the only call to controller is by pressing download button(s) , and not the filter button.

Comment: @ChrisG Could you please elaborate on the specifics of the AJAX call. Some code or a reference to the same is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Wrap your dynamic table rows with a `<tbody>` element. 2. Call code like `fetch('personTable.jsp?minage=30&maxage=40').then(r => r.text()).then(rows => document.querySelector('#dataTable tbody').innerHTML = rows;)` (obviously you'll want to insert the actual values into the URL) 3. create a controller on the Spring side that returns the table rows.

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery, so you can simply do `$('#dataTable tbody').load(url);` instead.

Comment: @ChrisG I see. Thanks a lot. So, you're suggesting to make a file named `personTable.jsp` on which there will be a creation of the table based on the arguments. And this page will receive the ajax request. Since we are loading the `tbody` of `dataTable` by what this page returns, it should only have this table right?
I just looked up the `load()` method of jQuery and tried relating that to what you said, so just wanted to make sure I got it correctly.

Comment: Yes, exactly; you compose the controller URL and pass it to `load()`, the server sends back the table rows and jQuery inserts them.